# Creating a function for triggering CSS animation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

What is the best way to **trigger/activate CSS** animation from within a function in AngularJS?

In my case, I have a slide, which has one `label` <> and a `button` <>.

When a user clicks on the button, I'm calling an API,  and on failure case, I  need to animate the label.

One way will be to use ng-class directive. In which creating a scope variable, and set and reset value using `$timeout` service.

But I'm thinking of making a function something like `playAnimation()` and call this function which will trigger the animation.

1. *What will be the steps for doing so in anularjs?*

I'm using angularjs version 1.5.

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: No... I just have included angular.js

Comment: If including jQuery doesn't matter you can easily accomplish that with **addClass('error-class')** and **removeClass('error-class')** methods of jQuery.

Comment: Beside JQuery any other efficient way for such things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating a function would be better than using `ng-class` as you initially suggested. You could them benefit from Angular's [animation classes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) (e.g. `ng-enter`, `ng-leave` etc), saving code in your scripts.

Comment: I have some different opinion,about which I'm also not sure. Currently I don't want to create variable just for adding and removing CSS classes. Also in my particular case I want to animate the label only when I am getting negative response from an API call.

Comment: I'm very new to AngularJS, as just wondering how to get thing done in correct way . thanks for your time and reply